# Update system app in android

Tags: android, android-source

I have developed an android app and put this as prebuilt APK in AOSP.
So the app will be installed in /system/app as a system app.

The app has update function itself by downloading and installing the newer version APK.

But it does not work because system app cannot be updated.
Is there any way to update self-made system app?

Comment: I have run my firmware. I am developing studying devices for students so i have made android devices and customized android os for these devices.

Comment: use the system signing certificates(same as OS signing) to sign your apk, and then try to update(over-install) app

Comment: you can maintain app version in your service end, and while consuming your services check users app version and your updated app version and return a url for upgrade if old app. handle this case in app accordingly and let users to update the app.

Comment: @AnandTiwari, Can you let me know how to get system signing certificate?

Comment: @ZhaoLin, I am not sure if OS is your own, signing certificate of OS, mean the certificate used to build OS, or you can contact your vendor support.

Comment: If you use the normal mechanism to install this, the replacement goes on /data and overrides the original on /system having the same name and signer.

Answer (score 2):

System app can be updated, in two ways:

1. Updated by the ota updating, this will change the app directly, and the app still exist on /system.
2. updated by using package install api, this need the new version apk have the same signature with the one on /system, and the new version will be installed on /data. That means, if the device is reset, the new version will lose.

Ota update is a normal way for system app updating.

Comment: Hi, what is package install api??

Comment: I think he means by pm install -r <package_name> right? Is this still valid on Android 10?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install an updated version of your original system app into the /data partition, provided that:
1.  Both app versions are signed with the same key;
2.  The updated app’s `versionCode` is greater than or equal to the original app’s.

One way to do this update is to use the following adb command: `adb install -r <your updated apk file>`. Then you can test your updated version without having to rebuild your AOSP code.

Note that your updated version in the /data partition will be removed via a factory data reset. In this case your original system app will take effect again.